# Could not find gradle 2.2.3

Tags: android, xml

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 during gradle sync 
my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

}
    Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
Searched in the following locations:

> file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android
>   Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :libraries:opencv

Comment: have you check classpath in build.gradle(project)?

Comment: yes farhana
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Comment: check for gradle update

Comment: i don't know why conflicts gradle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ok i'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Because you may have not specify where to take this Dependency from :

Add jcenter() along with mavenCentral() in your project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Check what is Maven and Jcenter from here :
https://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/

Comment: hi ABDevelopers i have tried but again show same error.

Comment: Add your both  Build.gradle(App) Build.gradle(Project) in your question.

Comment: Add your both Build.gradle(App) Build.gradle(Project) in your question.

Comment: Arrey it was an example just post your both Build.gradles file